# Flicker in Chrome on JS/CSS Header Resize

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, google-chrome

Everyone --
I'm running into a strange flicker issue in Chrome when I utilize the following JavaScript to modify the css/class display properties of some header elements in my Bootstrap template.

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
  if ($(window).scrollTop() > 100) {
    $('header').addClass('shrink');
  } else {
    $('header').removeClass('shrink');
  }
});
```

Here's a CodePen for the issue: https://codepen.io/simon315/pen/pobyozw

When the user scrolls down the page, the function runs, but if the user stops/slows their scroll at that point, the addClass and removeClass elements seem to go back-and-forth causing the state to flicker, but only in Chrome.  All other browsers seem to work as expected (e.g., Firefox, Safari, Edge, etc.).

Just so we're clear, the CodePen example only includes a small sample of the final header - the production version has other header elements that will resize/appear/disappear on scroll.

How can I prevent this from happening or is there another solution that would allow me to modify the header once the user scrolls past a certain point on the page?

Comment: I would suggest not changing the height of the header which in turn changes how far down the page you have scrolled.

Comment: Take a look at this CSS:  http://jsfiddle.net/bgb8oa1c/

Answer (score 1):

The issue was due to the use of "position: sticky" on the header element.  Changing this to "position: fixed" made the flicker disappear.  However, other design-specific challenges just popped up, so now on to deal with them.  Thanks, @natel for the sample css - that jogged my memory on css positioning.

Comment: Just a quick follow-up, if someone **needs** to use "position:sticky" for their element, like I did, a quick fix to get this to work when the user scrolls is to keep the "position:sticky", but have its property change to "position:fixed" once the user scrolls down the page.